# Too many values to unpack / Needs at least 3 values - OpenCV - Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

Here's the snippet of my code:

```
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(image,127,255,0)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
cnt = contours[0]
M = cv2.moments(cnt)
print M
```

At first it gave me the error:

```
Too many values to unpack.
```

Then I changed my code to this:

```
_,contours,_,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
```

There was a new error saying:

```
Needs at least 3 values
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: it returns: `img,contours,hierarchy` in opencv3.0 but only `contours,hierarchy` in 2.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it returns: img,contours,hierarchy in opencv3.0 but only contours,hierarchy in 2.4 –  berak

Comment: I guessed, any way glad that you find it!